# .net unit test crashes with "Cannot pass a GCHandle across AppDomains" when called from foreign thread

Tags: .net, nunit, c++-cli, resharper, appdomain

I am writing a C# unit test to test C++/CLI functionality that involves threads.

The C++/CLI code implements a DirectShow filter, the Windows API for rendering movies. This works thus that I create DirectShow objects, I tell it to run an AVI through my C++/CLI filters, waits until rendering is done, and then exits. My filter has a callback that gives the video frames to C# for processing. DirectShow works thus that it creates its own thread and calls my COM objects from this thread.

Now, this stuff works when I run my code normally, but when running a unit test from Resharper it fails with the error "Cannot pass a GCHandle across AppDomains".

What appears to go wrong is that Resharper uses AppDomains in its testrunner, and the DirectShow thread is somehow not associated with this appdomain.

So how do I make this test work from Resharper? Is there a NUnit/Resharper setting to control if appdomains are used? Can I tell the CLR somehow that a thread is assocated with a particular appdomain? Do you know any other pragmatic workarounds?

TIA Jan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get it working with the procedure described in http://www.lenholgate.com/archives/000856.html

This describes how to make an unmanaged function pointer to a method in a managed class. When you call this function pointer, you get in the managed appdomain where the object originally was created. This fixes my appdomain errors.

Comment: Thank you for this link. I was struggling a lot to get my event system working where a separate native thread was calling the managed world. I built a simple mechanism using a class holding `gcroot<Action^>` to prevent garbage collection of my delegates + function pointers created by `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate() ` pointing to my delegates. In my event triggers I simply call the function pointer and the AppDomain transition is done automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the ReSharper version that you are using. Try running the tests with the latest [ReSharper 5.0 Nightly Build](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+5.0+Nightly+Builds). The guys there had rewritten the test runner to support Nunit naively. If this doesn't work, I suggest you report this as an issue at their new [Bug Tracking system](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/RSRP).

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble. I managed to fix the root cause in the meantime, but I'll surely test with 5.0 soon enough.